# Julia: how to index an 'any' type array

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I am new in Julia. I want to replicate the results in Wollmann (2019).
However, it always give me this error: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Type{Array{Any, 100}}, ::Matrix{Int64}, ::Int64).

Here is the code:

```
i=1
hArray = Array{Any,100}
tbx_temp = (tbx_t.==(1996-1985))+(tbx_t.==(2000-1985))+(tbx_t.==(2005-1985))
hArray[i]=tbx_temp.*tbx_enter.*(sum(tbx_x1[:,3:4],dims=2).==0) .* sum(tbx_h_x[:,2:4],dims=2); i=i+1;
```

#tbx_t is an Int64 vector, and looks like this:

13824-element Vector{Int64}:
[1;1;1;...;27;27;27]

#tbx_enter is a bitvector, either 0 or 1.

#tbx_x1 is a float64 matrix:

13824×2 Matrix{Float64}:

[1.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0;...;0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]

#tbx_h_x is a bitmatrix, either 0 or 1
13824×3 BitMatrix:

[0 0 0; 0 1 0;...;1 0 1; 0 0 0]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `Any` unless you have to. Figure out what the type of the arrays is, and use that.

Answer (score 2):

The line `hArray = Array{Any,100}` simply describes *the type* of a 100-dimensional array.  It does not construct a 100-element vector.  To create such an array (without initializing its elements), use the [Array constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Core.Array-Tuple%7BUndefInitializer,%20Any%7D), or perhaps more clearly, the [Vector constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.Vector):

```
# Using Array constructor
hArray = Array{Any}(undef, 100)

#Using Vector constructor
hArray = Vector{Any}(undef, 100)
```

However, it is typically poor practice to use the `Any` type without good reason. For example, [performance can decrease when using abstract types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-abstract-container). Your snippet indicates that the elements of hArray are likely Float64. If that is the case, you can use:

```
hArray = Vector{Float64}(undef, 100)
```

Even if you aren't sure exactly which data type is appropriate, using a smaller abstract type such as `Number` or `Real` is better practice than using `Any`.